# concatenate video files using ffmpeg - garbled images but audio okay

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to concatenate video files so that next one follows the one before it when it is played. The formatting for all of the files are the same. The files all have audio & video.

I think I am very close (hopefully!) to getting this to work, but I have one final problem. The command below takes all of the mp4 files in my folder and creates a big mp4 file, which is the right size in total MB, but the images for all videos after the first video are garbled. The audio is okay (continues just fine from video to video). Also, I don't get any error messages.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i <(for f in /folder1/*.mp4; do echo "file '$f'"; done) -c copy /folder1/all.mp4
```

I'm not very familiar with ffmpeg yet, so I've just been trying the different suggestions I've found on the web. Can anyone suggest other things for me to try? (I've tried reading the FAQs, but I have to confess that I don't fully understand it. Also, there seems to be some posts about audio being missing after concatenation, but I haven't seen anything on images being garbled.) Thx in advance!

Comment: Thanks - I put it here because I saw other ffmpeg questions here. I haven't used Super User yet, and actually I'm not sure if I will know enough to draw a distinction between what questions go here & what shouldn't go here. I see a lot of questions getting docked (and have had that happen to me as well), so I wish people could be more understanding, but I guess if you know what you are doing, then questions like this could be annoying. There are two sides to every coin I guess. Thx for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had good luck using this ... avconv is a fork of ffmpeg

```
avconv -i 1.mp4 1.mpeg
avconv -i 2.mp4 2.mpeg
avconv -i 3.mp4 3.mpeg
cat 1.mpeg 2.mpeg 3.mpeg | avconv -f mpeg -i - -vcodec mpeg4 -strict experimental output.mp4
```

Comment: This does unnecessary additional lossy encoding steps which is slow and reduces the quality of the output. I would recommend using the [concat demuxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat) ([additional info](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate)) or [concat filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) instead, but `avconv` lacks those features available in `ffmpeg` from FFmpeg.

Comment: Great - thanks - I'll give this a try. It looks like avconv takes a few steps to install, so I'll need to do that first. I really appreciate the tip!!